# add a number in the beginning of a value depending on its length

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I tell `R` to add `0` in the beginning of a value (column `key`) if its length is less than `9`?

Sample data:

```
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Key = c("10032012", "10812012", "2073017", "10692013", "10892012", "10952014", "10972012", "560392013", "560372013", "56022012")

df = data.frame(id, Key)
```

Desired Output:

```
df_desired = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Key = c("010032012", 
"010812012", "02073017", "010692013", "010892012", "010952014", "010972012", 
"560392013", "560372013", "56022012")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: `df$Key <- ifelse(nchar(df$Key) < 9, paste0("0", df$Key), df$Key)`

Comment: Or `stringr::str_pad(df$Key, width = 9, pad = "0")`

Comment: Base R: `sprintf("%09d", as.integer(df$Key))`.

Comment: @stefan, when I do `df = df %>% stringr::str_pad(Key, width = 9, pad = "0")`, I get an error `Error in match.arg(side) : arg must be of length 1`

Comment: do `df = df %>% with(stringr::str_pad(Key, width = 9, pad = "0"))`

Comment: @RicVillalba, your first comment worked, you can add it as an answer with some explanation if needed, thank you. Or you can add all solutions in your answer

Comment: @RicVillalba, how does `with` fix it?

Comment: There are two things:  Pipe `%>%` injects the left value (df) as the first argument of the rigth function. [`with`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html) takes the first argument (df passed by %>%) and evaluates the second inside the frame of the first, thus no need to ful qualify variables i.e. Key stands for df$Key. I put some answers but not `with` because it is not about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers
For any character string:

```
df$Key <- ifelse(nchar(df$Key) < 9, paste0("0", df$Key), df$Key)
```

If they are all integer strings a canonical way would be:

```
df$Key <- sprintf("%09d", as.integer(df$Key))
```

using `dplyr` & `stringr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_desired <- df %>% mutate(Key = str_pad(Key, width = 9, pad = "0"))
```

Comment: You know what's strange when I export the `df` as a `csv`, the `csv` does not contains the zeros so I have to save it as an `xlsx`.

Comment: write.csv(df) should preserve zeroes see it in a notepad or similar.